# POST an xml file to server using ajax (XmlHttpRequest Object)

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, base64

I need to **POST** a long xml file (say of 10 kilo bytes size) to server from client browser
using XMLHTTPREQUEST or Microsoft Equivalent. How to post it using ajax? Should I do Base64 Encoding while sending because the data is longer (so that data remains unaltered by any error)? (if yes how to do it?). I am using Http POST Method. Is there any better way ? Following code do not work in Firefox:

```
var postxmldata = function(xmldata, location, method, async, param) {
    var params = param+"="+xmldata;
    var http = initXml();
    if(!http) return;
    http.open("POST", location, async);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", xmldata.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.

        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

Comment: You might want to read this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html

Comment: what does `do not work` mean? Is xmldata a string? Inspect request in browser console and provide more details

Comment: yes xmldata is the string representation of an xml file's content which may be upto 10 kilobytes.

Comment: so what happens with  request? timeout? have to look in console

Comment: It only says: Failure. But I analysed that this Failure word is not coming from the server but it is some ajax error.

Comment: I imagine converting xml to javascriot object/array and sending as JSON would cut size down significantly but would depend on complexity of xml tags themselves such as having many attributes etc

Comment: Since you're specifying `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should URL-encode `xmldata`. I think that should be all you need to do.

Comment: If you use jQuery, its `$.ajax()` and `$.post()` functions will take care of all the necesary encoding for you if you provide the data as a structured object.